# AWS Code Pipeline deploy results in a 404

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to create a pipeline for an existing application. It is a React/Java Spring Boot application. It usually gets bundled into a single war file and uploaded to ElasticBeanstalk. I created my codebuild project and when I run it manually it will generate a war file that I can then upload to ElasticBeanstalk and everything works correctly. The buildspec for that is below:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the install phase...
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn -Pprod package -X
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - mv target/cogcincinnati-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war cogcincinnati-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
artifacts:
  files:
    - cogcincinnati-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

When I run this build step in my pipeline it generates a zip file that gets dropped onto S3. My deploy step takes that build artifact and sends it to ElasticBeanstalk. Elasticbeanstalk does not give me any errors, but when I navigate to my url, I get a 404.

I have tried uploading the zip directly to Elasticbeanstalk and I get the same result. I have unzipped the file and it does appear to have all of my project files.

When I look at the server logs, I do not see any errors. I don't understanding why codebuild appears to be generating a war file when I run it manually, but a zip when executed in code pipeline.

Comment: Are you deploying under a context path? If so, please read about setting the base href on https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#building-an-executable-jar--war-file

Comment: I updated my reference to 
new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/cogcincinnati/' }) and redeployed. It didn't work. I think you're probably correct that it is probably incorrect. I think the underlying issue is that it isn't deploying the correct profile.

Answer (score 1):

Change artifacts war file name to ROOT.war this will resolve your problem actually your application is deployed successfully but on a different path, this is tomcat inbuild functionality by changing the ROOT it will run the application on '/'

So updated buildspec.yml will be

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the install phase...
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn -Pprod package -X
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - mv target/cogcincinnati-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ROOT.war
artifacts:
  files:
    - ROOT.war
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your application is failing, you should review the logs from the Beanstalk environment, specially:

- "tomcat8/catalina.out"
- "tomcat8/catalina.[date].log"

[1] Viewing logs from Amazon EC2 instances in your Elastic Beanstalk environment - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

For more details about using Tomcat platform on EB environment, you can refer to this document:
  - Using the Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat platform - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html

About the folder structuring in your project, please refer to this document:
  - Structuring your project folder - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform-directorystructure.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding discard-paths: yes at the end of the buildspec.yml file. That will help you resolving the path error.